# Handling Multiple UserForm Controls With One Event Handler - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, events, onclick, handler

I created many buttons dynamically (creating schedule) and want all of them do the same thing during Click event (OnClick property).

Of course, I can create max number of buttons on the form beforehand and set them invisible, and so forth, while adding "call SomeEvent" on their Click event considering that there can be over a thousand buttons. This would be very tedious.

Therefore, simplified:

I created new class btnClass`

```
Public WithEvents ButtonEvent As MsForms.CommandButton
Private Sub ButtonEvent_Click()
    MsgBox "hey"
End Sub
```

Then, in my UserForm, where I dynamically create buttons I added this (I also have Collection, to remove buttons later), in its simplified form:

```
Dim btnColl As Collection
Dim Buttons As New btnClass

Set btnColl = New Collection
Set Buttons = New btnClass

For i = 0 To btnCount

         Set theButton = Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btn" & i, True)
         With theButton
            .Height = 17
            .Caption = "btn" & i
          End With


        Set Buttons.ButtonEvent = theButton
        btnColl.Add theButton, theButton.Name


Next i
```

But nothing happens when I click dynamically created buttons. What am I missing?

---UPDATED
---@FaneDuru Provided solution which worked for me

```
 ReDim Buttons(0 To btnCount, 0 To dtDiff)


For labelcounter = 0 To dtDiff 'add date labels
    Set theLabel = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblDay" & labelcounter, True)
    With theLabel

        .Caption = VBA.Format(DateAdd("d", labelcounter, bDate), "d-mm-yy")
        .Left = 15 + 44 * labelcounter
        .BackColor = vbBlack
        .Font.Bold = True
        .ForeColor = vbWhite
        .Height = 13
        .Width = 40
        .Top = 85
    End With
    For i = 0 To btnCount 'add time buttons
        pTime = DateAdd("n", i * dur, begTime)
        Set theButton = Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btn" & CDate(theLabel.Caption & " " & TimeValue(pTime)), True)
        With theButton
            .Height = 17
            .Caption = VBA.Format(TimeValue(pTime), "hh:mm")
            '.Caption = CDate(theLabel.Caption & " " & TimeValue(pTime))
            .Left = 15 + 44 * labelcounter
            .BackColor = vbGreen
            .Width = 40
            .Top = 100 + 18 * i
        End With


    Set Buttons(i, labelcounter).ButtonEvent = theButton
    btnColl.Add theButton, theButton.Name



    Next i

Next labelcounter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way, only for the last created button an event is allocated. You must declare an array of classes... I also played a little with the `Left` property of the newly created buttons, only to have the possibility to test their click event. Try the next approach, please:

```
Option Explicit

Private btnColl As New Collection
Dim Buttons() As New btnClass

Private Sub btCreate_Click()
 Dim btnCount As Long, theButton As CommandButton, i As Long

 btnCount = 3
 ReDim Buttons(0 To btnCount)
 For i = 0 To btnCount

         Set theButton = Me.Controls.aDD("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btn" & i, True)
         With theButton
            .height = 17
            .Caption = "btn" & i
            .left = 50 * i
          End With

        btnColl.aDD theButton, theButton.Name
        Set Buttons(i).ButtonEvent = theButton
 Next i
End Sub

Private Sub btdelete_Click() 'buttons deletion...
 Dim i As Long
   For i = 1 To btnColl.count
       Me.Controls.Remove (btnColl(i).Name)
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe don't need a separate Collection to hold the buttons, since each element of `Buttons`  has a `ButtonEvent`  field which is the underlying button object ?

Comment: @Tim Williams: I think he uses that collection for newly created buttons deletion... He said something about this aspect and that's why I kept it in my code. I will also post the deletion button code, as I imagine it. To, maybe, make more sense...

Comment: @FaneDuru: thank you. I will check tomorrow to see if it works.
Regarding, moving buttons to the right, I just accidentally deleted changing .Left property.
I think I tried below array solution, but when later I wanted to remove buttons via collection I had error... Doesn't assigning Buttons.ButtonEvent = theButton in the loop adds the handler all of them? Will check again to see what the problem was... The code is huge, it is difficult to trace everything. Nevertheless, I will do with array and post the whole code here with deletion... Thank you again for your great help

Comment: @ulviii: No need to post everything, I would say. Try please, to test the code above (keeping also the variable declarations as I set) and after seeing it working (I tested it and it works on my computer) we can think about other improvements if necessary... About the array issue, it is important to be `Redim` at the newly buttons to be created. Otherwise, it may return an error. Anyhow, I wait a little feedback after you have the possibility to test it.

Comment: @FaneDuru: works perfectly, huge thanks!
First time I tried with arrays on my own I forgot to add the second dimension, and would have given completely with out your help!

Comment: @ulviii: Glad I was able to help! But we here, when an answer solves our problems, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In such a case, when someone looking for the some type of problem, will know that the code works...