# Code to account for all checkboxes in a userform?

Tags: vba, loops, date, checkbox, userform

I have code on a userform that contains several checkboxes and several DTPickers.

The code looks like so:

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox11_Click()
If CheckBox11.Value = True Then
    DTPicker22.Enabled = True
Else
    DTPicker22.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox12_Click()
If CheckBox12.Value = True Then
    DTPicker24.Enabled = True
Else
    DTPicker24.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

The Userform contains a lot of checkboxes that have clauses next to them. Upon their completion the DTPicker will enable entering the date of completion.

Whilst this does what I want, it only enables one DTPicker when the checkbox is ticked per private sub. There has to be some way to make this so I wouldn't need to create different private subs for every checkbox click event.

Could you also tell me where to put it, as in, what event?

Comment: This might help [Handling Multiple UserForm Controls With One Event Handler - VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61737670/handling-multiple-userform-controls-with-one-event-handler-vba-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "control array" is the typical approach for something like this.

See:
http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

eg:

Class module `clsEvents`

```vb
Option Explicit

'Handle events for a checkbox and a date control, associated with a worksheet cell
Private WithEvents m_CB As MSForms.CheckBox
Private WithEvents m_DP As DTPicker
Private m_dateCell As Range

'set up the controls and the cell
Public Sub Init(cb As MSForms.CheckBox, dp As DTPicker, rng As Range)
    
    Set m_CB = cb
    Set m_DP = dp
    Set m_dateCell = rng
    
    If rng.Value > 0 Then
        cb.Value = True
        m_DP.Value = rng.Value
    Else
        cb.Value = False
    End If
    
    m_DP.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    
End Sub

Private Sub m_CB_Change()
    m_DP.Enabled = (m_CB.Value = True)
End Sub

Private Sub m_DP_Change()
    m_dateCell.Value = m_DP.Value 'update the cell
End Sub
```

Userform:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim colObj As Collection 'needs to be a Global to stay in scope

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim obj As clsEvents, i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set colObj = New Collection
    'loop over controls and create a class object for each set
    ' 3 pairs of controls on my test form...
    For i = 1 To 3
        Set obj = New clsEvents
        obj.Init Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i), _
                  Me.Controls("DTPicker" & i), _
                  ws.Cells(i, "B")
        colObj.Add obj
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect this encapsulates everything perfectly, amazing! I have to go learn to do this myself next time, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd recommend is following a proper naming convention. "CheckBox11" and "DTPciker1" are really vague and once you get further into your code, you'll forget which control is which. I would recommend naming them something that relates the two control together, like "firstDate" and "firstDateDTP". My alternate answer below uses this approach.

You could make a public function that enables the DTPicker based upon the checkbox's value.

```
Public Function EnableDTPicker(myPicker as String, enableBool as Boolean)

    UserFormName.Controls(myPicker).Enabled = enableBool

End Function
```

Then, you can call the function in your CheckBox123_Click() subs like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox123_Click()
    EnableDTPicker("thePickerName", CheckBox123.Value)
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could make a timer event that runs x number of seconds that just loops through the controls and performs the checks as needed. [See this page on how to set up the timer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon) Using the code in the link shown, You could do something along the lines of:

```
'Put this in Workbook events
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

'Put this in a Module
Public Sub EventMacro()
    With UserForm1
        For each ctrl in .Controls
            If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
                'The code below assumes the naming convention outlined above is followed
                .Controls(ctrl.Name & "DTP").Enabled = ctrl.Value
            End If
        Next ctrl
    End With

    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
End Sub
```